# add curly braces to simple ifs

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pdt

I have the following code:

```
if ($foo)
    bar();
```

When I format the code or save it, is it possible for eclipse to automatically put an opening and closing curly brace into it? So it would look like so:

```
if ($foo) {
    bar();
}
```

Thanks in advance,
Ramon

Comment: The default Eclipse Java formatter will do this.  You have to execute the formatter yourself.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm a bit new to Eclipse but I'm using the PDT version, is the Java formatter still runnable on that? I thought the PHP formatter is a different thing?

Comment: Sorry, I've been answering Java questions all morning.  My mistake.  You could see if there's a PHP formatter in Eclipse.  You would right click on the code in the editor and look for Source -> Format.

Answer (score 1):

Click on `Window > Preferences` in preference window type `save` then you will get below form as shown below

[image]

Follow steps mentioned in picture. After clicking on **Configure** button you will get dialog as shown below.

[image]

Click OK. Everything is ready now.

Comment: Thanks, while this exists on Java, it does not on PDT. I don't understand why they didn't include such an important feature.

Comment: Check the code formatter in PDT  if not exist raise a bug here https://bugs.eclipse.org choose PDT as product